# Can CloudFormation Create a PipeLine Manual Approval Action through Template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

Reading through this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/approvals-action-add.html

it sounds like you can only create a manual approval step through the UI Console or through CLI BUT NOT through CloudFormation Template?

Edgar

Comment: Thank you.  This is how I got it to work.

```
      Stages: 
        -
          Name: ApproveDeployment
          Actions: 
            - 
              Name: ApproveDeployment
              ActionTypeId: 
                Category: Approval 
                Owner: AWS 
                Version: 1
                Provider: Manual
              Configuration:
                CustomData: !Ref CustomMessage
                ExternalEntityLink: !Ref EntityLink
                NotificationArn: !Ref NotificationArn
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, CloudFormation does support this.

You just need to set Provider for resource [ActionTypeId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codepipeline-pipeline-stages-actions-actiontypeid.html) (Pipeline -> Stage -> Action -> ActionTypeId) as **Manual** and that's it. More info about provider type - [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html#actions-valid-providers).

Examle:

```
DeliveryPipeline:
    Properties:
      ...
      Stages:
        ...
        - Actions:
            - ActionTypeId:
                Category: Approval
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: Manual
                Version: '1'
              Configuration:
                NotificationArn: <<arn>>
              InputArtifacts: []
              Name: TestApproval
              RunOrder: 1
          Name: Development_Approval
          ...
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
```